# Alternative for |(pipe) operator

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a alternative for `|` operator in bash shell for redirecting output of command as input to the next command. Is there any alternative?

something like :

```
command1 | command2 | command3
```

with alternative to:

```
command1 X command2 X command3
```

`X` will be use in place of `|`. Is it possible to avoid of using `|` and replace it with the actual operator of that?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: @choroba is that important? just for avoid of using `|`.

Comment: I'm just checking it's not an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @KasiyA, I still don't understand the purpose of this question. Are you trying to avoid running the commands in subshells? Are you offended by the shape of the `|`? The 2nd question is snarky, but what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's still not clear. Do you want to duplicate output of the first command? Then `tee` with process substitution might be what you need.

Comment: @glennjackman as for me, I came to this post because in ultra vnc I cannot send | pipe to remote console, its not getting typed. Maybe that was kasiyA was asking

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The equivalent of `command1 | command2` is `command2 < <(command1)`

This can be extended to three (or more) commands too.

`command3 < <(command2 < <(command1))`

```
$ lspci | grep 'Network'
 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

$ grep 'Network' <(lspci)
 02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

$ lspci | grep 'Network' | grep -o 'controller'
 controller

$ grep -o 'controller' < <(grep 'Network' < <(lspci))
 controller
```

However, as Oli suggested, although this may produce the same output, it isn't technically the same as a pipe.

> <(..) turns the internal command output's STDOUT into a file handler
>   (that the command, grep in your example) opens. When you pipe, the
>   reading command is reading directly from STDIN (which is being filled
>   with the piped command's STDOUT). Subtle differences but can be
>   significant with commands that only know how to read STDIN.

Comment: This isn't technically correct. `<(..)` turns the internal command output's STDOUT into a file descriptor (that the command, `grep` in your example) opens. When you pipe, the reading command is reading directly from STDIN (which is being filled with the piped command's STDOUT). Subtle differences but can be significant with commands that only know how to read STDIN.

Comment: edited with Oli's suggestion: `cmd2 < <(cmd1)` is more like it.

Comment: @Oli Added your comment to the answer to highlight the difference.

Comment: @Oli, I'm not sure where you got that information but it appears to be wrong.  In both cases the shell creates a `pipe(2)`, and `fork()`s and `dup2()`s the pipe to the stdin of the one process and stdout of the other.  The difference seems to be that with the parenthesis, the program is run in a sub shell, so for instance, if you ctrl-c, the program in the subshell is not interrupted and is "lost".  This actually feels like a bug in bash to me.

Comment: @psusi what Oli means is a program like `tr`. `tr` only knows how to read from stdin. It cannot open files, unlike grep or awk, which can open files or read from stdin. So you *have* to do `tr < <(foo)`, `tr <(foo)` won't work like `grep ... <(foo)` or `sed ... <(foo)`.

Comment: @muru, you seem to be rather confused.  `tr < foo` will make tr read from the file foo.  `tr <(foo)` tries to run a *program* named foo, then feed its output to tr.  None of this requires tr to have an option to read from a file.

Comment: @psusi nope, try `tr -cd '[[:space:]]' <(seq 1 10)` and see what happens.

Comment: The point is that, despite the leading ,`<`, this is *not* a redirection. `<()` in a command line is replaced entirely with the path to a file, a file that happens to be the stdout of the command inside the process substitution, but a path nonetheless. Whether you want to provide a path to a file or redirect from (or to it, if `>()`) is a separate question. That's why this is process *substitution* and not process redirection - like command substitution, the thing is substituted with something, a filename in one and output in the other.

Comment: @muru, OHH! I see what you mean now.

Comment: It is worth noting that this is equivalent;
`lspci > >(grep 'Network' > >(grep -o 'controller'))`
and reads more conveniently left to right.