# Start and terminate TAIL running via SSH using BASH

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, tail

I am trying to monitor the changes of a file via SSH and copy the changes of it in local computer using BASH. I ran the following command to monitor and copy:

```
ssh root@192.168.88.238 "tail -F /media/sdcard/SA000001.log"> ~/Desktop/Modem.log
```

Which works perfectly. But then it keeps running. I want to terminate the tail and the ssh after certain period (Or when a certain string is found).

I tried the following command, but it didn't work:

```
ssh -t root@192.168.88.238 "tail -F /media/sdcard/SA000001.log && sleep 10 && exit"> ~/Desktop/Modem.log
```

I also tried passing `exit` and the ASCII value of `CTRL+C` via echo, but was unable to end/kill the tail and ssh.

Then I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/sh 

ssh -t root@192.168.88.238 "tail -F /media/sdcard/SA000001.log | while read TEMPLOGLINE"> ~/Desktop/Modem.log

do
   [[ "${TEMPLOGLINE}" == *"temp"* ]] && pkill -P $$ tail
done

exit
```

I have also tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh 

ssh -t root@192.168.88.238 "tail -F /media/sdcard/SA000001.log"> ~/Desktop/Modem.log

ssh -t root@192.168.88.238 "/X03"
ssh -t root@192.168.88.238 "exit"
```

Here is my bash file at this moment:

```
#!/bin/sh 

ssh -t root@192.168.88.238 "tail -F /media/sdcard/SA000001.log"> ~/Desktop/Modem.log
```

Any suggestions on how I should proceed with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ssh root@192.168.88.238 tail -F /media/sdcard/SA000001.log | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
    if [[ $line =~ 'temp' ]]; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

Save the script above as `foo.sh` or whatever, make it executable (`chmod a+x foo.sh`) and then run it:

```
foo.sh > ~/Desktop/Modem.log
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the command you need to do the job:

```
ssh USER@HOST "bash -c 'sed '/PATTERN/q' <(tail -F /path/to/dest/log)'"> inlocal.log
```

you can use `awk` instead as following as well:

```
ssh USER@HOST "bash -c 'awk '1;/PATTERN/{exit}' <(tail -F /path/to/dest/log)'"> inlocal.log
```

Comment: That does work, but has the (possible) drawback that it won't show the file grow in "real time" because `sed` buffers its output so lines will be printed in bunches.

Comment: @terdon I have tested 100% successfully my answer! but buffering Yes it does

Comment: Yes, and it absolutely works and I have upvoted it. All I am saying is that it won't show the results in "real time" because `sed` buffers its output. This means it will take a few seconds for the first output to appear. I don't know if this is a problem for the OP (won't be if they just want everything saved in a file) but I felt it was worth mentioning.

Comment: What is the point of `sed '/PATTERN/q' <( tail -F logfile )` here instead of `tail -F logfile | sed '/PATTERN/q`?

Comment: please refer to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/564380/283843)