# Rearrange file contents based on two columns

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Input: file contains data:

```
ID   Location  Domaind
1     20        X
1     5         y
1     25        Z
2     1         L
2     150       N
2     50        M
3     50        J
4     33        k
4      3        I
```

I have to arrange these Data based on ID and Location. Mean first arranged ID=1 in ascending order of location then print domains from left to right same order as in location.

Output like:

```
1      Y-X-Z
2      L-M-N
3        J
4       I-K
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `awk` command as following.

```bsh
awk '{arr[$1]=arr[$1]d[$1]$NF; d[$1]="-"}
    END{for (x in arr) print x"\t"arr[x]}' <(sort -V <(column -t infile))
```

- `column -t infile` reads the file and here prints just the columns in left alignment.
- `sort -V` sorts the file as `V`ersion sort.
- and `awk` just reading to the fields into array called `arr` with the key as column#1 and value as respecting column#3, then at the end print the elements.
- Here I used process substitution `<(sort -V <(column -t infile))` while we could use Pipes instead if your shell doesn't support it as **muru** pointed `/bin/dash` doesn't.

The output is:

```
ID      Domaind
1       Y-X-Z
2       L-M-N
3       J
4       I-k
```

---

Or you can use as below instead of holding whole file into array.

```bsh
awk 'p!=$1 &&p{print l}{l=($1!=p)?$1FS$3:l"-"$3;p=$1}' <(sort -V <(column -t in))
```

Comment: Why use process substitution instead of simply piping? `column -t file | sort -V | awk ...`?

Comment: I have no reason except, because I like this syntax `<( <() )` and don't like Pipes :P

Comment: Also, if you have sorted input, you don't need to keep the elements saved till `END`. YOu can accumulate till `$1` changes: `awk '$1 == prev {out=out"-"$3; next} out{print prev, out} {out=$3; prev=$1}'`

Comment: If you have no reason, then you should warn that process substitution may not be available in all shells in Ubuntu. `/bin/dash` doesn't have it.

Comment: Ah, [I didn't know this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971229/rearrange-file-contents-based-on-two-columns#comment1555931_971245) and [it's for long time back I was looking for an alternative to Pipe](https://askubuntu.com/q/564380/283843). thanks. also I can add your suggested command into my answer or you will post with your own :   )

Comment: That question still strikes me as weird. `|` is the actual operator in as  much as it has been around decades before `<()` was introduced. You can add the suggestions to your answer (that's why I commented here, so you can improve the post.)

Comment: @muru thanks, I used different way of your command suggested. thank you

Comment: If we have line as this one: `1     20        X X`, the second `X` will disappear. Is it possible to tell awk to output from `$3` to `$NF`?

Comment: @pa4080 Actually first `X` disappear since i'm getting `$NF`, for that use `awk '{one=$1;$1=$2="";arr[one]=arr[one]d[one]$0; d[one]="-"}
    END{for (x in arr) print x"\t"arr[x]}' <(sort -V <(column -t in))` or removing whitespaces, `awk '{one=$1;$1=$2="";gsub(/[ \t]+/,"",$0);arr[one]=arr[one]d[one]$0; d[one]="-"} END{for (x in arr) print x"\t"arr[x]}
' <(sort -V <(column -t in))`