# How do I find the process with the highest load?

Tags: command-line, cpu-load

I have a single core VPS with a load average that goes beyond 25 at times. When it reaches that, it becomes unbearably slow, and even commands run through `dash`, which is faster and uses less RAM than `bash`, takes a while to run. How can I track down what process is causing the high load?

Comment: `sudo apt install htop` gives you a useful text-mode tool for this purpose (more user friendly than the standard `top`). But `top` is good if you want a small foot-print.

Comment: The load queue length indicates how many processes are ready to use CPU.  This may not necessarily be a single process causing the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can install `htop`. Good thing about `htop` is that it will show you your usage per CPU, as well as a meaningful text graph of your memory and swap usage right at the top.

To install `htop`:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Start it:

```
htop
```

[image]

Press `F6` to sort the processes, then using the navigation key you can choose `PERCENT_CPU` and press enter.

[image]

Or you can use `top` in this way ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/show-top-five-cpu-consuming-processes-with-ps)):

```
top -b -n 1 | head -n 12
```

Comment: As a shortcut, you can use `P` to sort by processor usage, `M` for memory, or `T` for time, and `t` to return to the tree layout.

Comment: Interestingly, `htop` has some basic mouse support. If you click on the columns, it will allow you to sort by them too (if I'm not mistaken). There are some other operations that work with your mouse.

Answer (score 13):

<sup>The below is merely stolen from [Unix.SE: Find the process which is taking maximum CPU usage if CPU usage is more than 60%?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166263/find-the-process-which-is-taking-maximum-cpu-usage-if-cpu-usage-is-more-than-60), though of course adapted to this question.</sup>

#### list processes by specific CPU usage

```
ps ahux --sort=-c | awk '{if($3>0.0)printf"%s %6d %s\n",$3,$2,$11}'
```

This gives a list of the processes which have a CPU usage `>0.0`%, you can change this value according to your needs, e.g. `>50.0`. Each line contains the CPU usage in percent, the PID and the file of the process.

#### list processes with the most CPU usage

```
ps ahux --sort=-c | awk 'NR<=5{printf"%s %6d %s\n",$3,$2,$11}'
```

This shows the top 5 (`NR<=5`) processes currently causing the most CPU load.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I was studying `awk` and I played with the other two answers. Here is the result:

- Get only the the process with the most higher CPU usage, using `ps aux`:

  ```
  ps auxh | awk -v max=0 '{if($3>max){CPU=$3; PID=$2; NAME=$11; max=$3}} END{printf "%5s %6d %s\n",CPU,PID,NAME}'
  ```
- Get the three processes with the most higher CPU usage, using `top`:

  ```
  top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR>7 && NR<11 {printf "top: %5s %6d %s %s\n",$9,$1,$12,$13}'
  ```
- Get the three processes with the most higher CPU usage, using `ps aux`:

  ```
  ps auxh --sort=-c | awk 'NR<=3 {printf "ps:  %5s %6d %s\n",$3,$2,$11}'
  ```

*I've tried to run the last two commands simultaneously (with `<command>; wait; <command>` and `<command> & <command> &`), but then I've realised it is not possible at all :)*

---

References:

- The other two nice answers from the current question (and [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971229/rearrange-file-contents-based-on-two-columns/971245?noredirect=1#comment1556786_971245) of @αғsнιη).
- [Find the max value of column 1 and print respective record from column 2 from file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170204/find-the-max-value-of-column-1-and-print-respective-record-from-column-2-from-fi).
- [How to run awk for some number of lines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89640/how-to-run-awk-for-some-number-of-lines)

Comment: The last one doesn't show the process with the most CPU usage, but starts with the second one, you probably meant `NR>=2` there – turns out `ps` provides the option `h` which omits the header line, see my updated answer.

Comment: @dessert, you are right, previously it was `NR>=2`, but `NR>1` is short :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for `top`!

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head

ps -Flww -p %PID
```

just use the PIDs from the output of the first command and place it on the "%PID" place. Just using the man page:

To see every process with a user-defined format:
ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm
ps axo stat,euid,ruid,tty,tpgid,sess,pgrp,ppid,pid,pcpu,comm
ps -Ao pid,tt,user,fname,tmout,f,wchan -l
-l - Long format. The -y option is often useful with this. -F Extra full format. See the -f option, which -F implies. w Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.

-p pidlist Select by PID. This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in pidlist. Identical to p and --pid.

Comment: Please add a explanation to the `ps` options

Comment: can you add this explanation to your answer?

Comment: Done as requested

Answer (score 1):

Use `top` command

> `top` - **display Linux processes**
>
> The  top  program  provides  a dynamic real-time view of a running
>   system.  It can display
>          system summary information as well as a list  of  processes  or  threads  currently  being
>          managed by the Linux kernel.  The types of system summary information shown and the types,
>          order and size of information displayed for processes are all user configurable  and  that
>          configuration can be made persistent across restarts.

[source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/top.1.html)

[good youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jB6dS3_xdBA)