# system freezes randomly and responds in a while on ubuntu 22.10

Tags: freeze

I just moved from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.10 on my [HP Notebook - 15-ay542tu laptop](https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c05366604) which has

```
CPU: Intel i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
RAM: 12GB RAM
400 GB SSD (ubuntu installed here)
1TB storage disk
```

#### Problem

The system freezes randomly for a minute or two and comes back online.

- It used to happen even on windows (but there were so many bloated softwares running, therefore I thought high CPU usage was the problem).
- The frequency of freezing increased on Ubuntu than on windows (contrary to my expectations). On windows, it used to be 2-3 times in an hour. On Ubuntu it became 8-10 times in an hour while I only just webbrowswer with 7-8 open tabs.

#### My conclusions so far

- I think its not **high CPU usage or insufficient RAM/Swap:**
  result of `top`

```
top - 14:04:25 up  1:08,  1 user,  load average: 5.51, 3.42, 2.96
Tasks: 253 total,   2 running, 251 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5.7 us,  1.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  11860.4 total,   7889.6 free,   1455.6 used,   2515.1 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  10240.0 total,  10240.0 free,      0.0 used.   9554.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                   
   1221 hp        20   0 4675648 267916 130600 S  13.7   2.2   3:46.93 gnome-shell                                                                                                                               
   6977 hp        20   0  568824  52152  39284 R   6.2   0.4   0:04.44 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                           
   7433 hp        20   0   21824   4096   3212 R   1.2   0.0   0:00.97 top                                                                                                                                       
     22 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.6   0.0   0:05.73 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                               
     58 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.6   0.0   0:01.74 kworker/1:1H-events_highpri                                                                                                               
     92 root       0 -20       0      0      0 D   0.6   0.0   0:05.97 kworker/u9:0+i915_flip
```

- I think its not **SSD or storage disk**

for SSD:
[image]
for storage disk:
[image]

What is it then? I am clueless. I don't know how to zero-in on the cause of these freezes.

#### No. of freezes are more on ubuntu than on windows

**EDIT:** Now that I've been using Ubuntu for 2 days. I noticed that no. of freezes have increased phenomenally on Ubuntu. I have no clue why. System resources are consumed less on Ubuntu but freezes are more when compared to windows.

I don't know if its relevant but at the time of booting i get this message before login screen is shown
[image]

Also today morning system crashed and showed this error
[image]

#### EDIT 2: When I run from live usb there are no freezes

I tried running Ubuntu live from USB (without installing) then there are no freezes. This immediately makes me think that the SSD on which ubuntu was installed is at fault. But I don't see any errors in SMART data.

for SSD:
[image]

What could be the issue? Is it the SSD that might be causing these freezes? What should I do now. The disk is still under warranty

Comment: The system load appears rather high. Based on the model of CPU that you use, it really shouldn't exceed `3.00` for very long. Do you have a lot of USB devices (particularly USB *storage* devices) that are active at the same time?

Comment: @matigo Yes, I have another 1TB external hardrive connected & a USB pen drive connected. keyboard & mouse are also connected via usb.

Comment: One thing that I have seen with certain kinds of machines is a noticeable increase in system load when there's too much being sent across a single USB channel (regardless of OS). This can be the result of sustained data transfers, suboptimal hardware drivers, exhausted file buffers, or some combination thereof. The key will be determining what process(es) cause an increased CPU load (note that load is not equivalent to usage (as a percentage)). Once identified, it may be possible to optimise the system accordingly 

Comment: @matigo Can you please direct me how to go about identifying them.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/973299/1222991) and [a bit of `iotop`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/iotop.8.html) should give you the basics to identify what your system is spending so many resources on 

Comment: I had the same issue with a desktop PC, after some months of trial and errors, the issue was finally a bad power cable. I would recommend checking the hardware first, since it happened on windows as well. Clean-up, contacts check and so on.Maybe the power cable has a bad contact and it connects and disconnects 100 times per minute or maybe RAM or hdd contacts are loose or covered in dust.
Good luck.

Comment: But mine is a laptop. Can powercable still cause a trouble in laptop? I will try nevertheless. Than you for answering

Comment: Thanks @matigo. But doesn't htop show the cpu usage at that instant. How to identify the process which has higest cpu load?

Comment: @claws by default htop sort based on CPU%. If you find it otherwise, you may change it using F6 then Up/Down to select another sorting base. Something you may try too is to check RAM as in https://askubuntu.com/q/917961/26246 , also you may go far and remove one memory bank use 8Gb alone then other one 4Gb alone see if you still experiencing freezes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer might be in your BIOS.  The boot message before login screen is trying to latch onto the TPM information in MSFT0101 to show that you have a legitimate Windows system. It may have been corrupted during its MS Windows lifetime.

You will want to check ACPI settings in your BIOS and try to turn this off.

Also this article tells you how to disable ACPI in your BIOS.
https://www.compuhoy.com/how-do-i-turn-off-acpi-mode-in-bios/#How_do_I_change_my_ACPI_settings_in_BIOS