# Alternative of the pipe (I) operator

Tags: command-line, bash

I did a research on this, found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564380/alternative-for-pipe-operator), but it doesn't answer my question.

I'm aware, that the syntax `expression1 | expression2` means ***take whatever is the result of expression1 and feed it to the expression2***.

Now, semantically, it should be the same as `expression2` `expression1` - to just take the result of expression1 and provide it explicitly to the expression2 as an argument. However, this doesn't work.

In programming, if you have `print(2+4)`, first `2+4` is calculated, and it's then printed. Concept seems the same here.. but no. Seems like I don't understand something quite clear. Any good clarification of this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the downvoted would give a feedback on it, it'd been just amazing. Clicking down is easy sport.

Comment: I didn't downvote this question (*yet*). `Now, semantically, it should be the same as expression2 expression1` - well, because?

Comment: What is `well, because`?.. can you just explain to me this point if you know it? try to help, if you're able to, except downvoting sport. I don't get this concept.

Comment: I'm asking you to explain why you think that `expression1 | expression2` *SHOULD* be the same as `expression2 expression1`.

Comment: This seems like a generic [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question, not specifically Ubuntu-related.

Comment: @user535733 right.. just wasn't really sure where I could find generic Unix/Linux forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Result* and *output* are different concepts. As are *argument* and *input*.

```
command1 | command2
```

Takes the *output* of command1 and feeds it to *input* of command2.

```
command2 command1
```

Runs command2 with one argument, the string "command1". It's definitely not the same thing.

The pipe can be replaced by *Process Substitution* and *Redirection*, though. That's probably what you imagined:

```
command2 < <(command1)
```

`<` means "read the input from here", and `<(...)`  runs the enclosed command(s) and creates a "filename" that can be read from.

Comment: Thanks. So `command1` in the second example is considered as a bare array of characters (String) rather than a program/expression call?

Comment: Yes. There are several more tricks, e.g. Command Substitution `$(...)` that turns output to arguments.

Comment: I got the point.. but it still is not really easily clicking into mind.. just to make it one more time sure: So, `exp1 | exp2` is to execute `exp1` and take the output and feed it into `exp2` as an argument, but `exp2 exp1` means to pass the bare String value `"exp1"` to the `exp2`. Right?

Comment: No, not as an argument, as an input. `exp1 $(exp2)` would interpret the output as argument(s).

Answer (score 3):

There are two very different concepts afoot here, even if they can both be used to provide data to a program:

1. **command arguments**: this is an array/list of strings that are available to the program when it starts, they can be accessed (in any order) with just a memory reference. But they have to exist before the program is started, and their total size is limited (around 2MB IIRC). In a shell these are passed like this:

   ```
   command arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
   ```
2. **standard input** (a.k.a. **stdin**): this is an input stream, that is accessed with file operations, and has to be read sequentially (no "random access"). But its size is potentially infinite and data can be added to it while the program that reads it is running. There are many ways to provide a stdin to a program, the two most frequent are:

   - reading from a file:

     ```
     command < file
     ```
   - using the output of another program:

     ```
     command1 | command2
     ```

These two methods can coexist, arguments are generally used to tell how to process (for instance, sort parameters), while stdin is fed with what to process (data to be sorted).

It is the shell that provides the arguments to the program, so the arguments must exist as strings in the shell data. By contast, for stdin the shell is just playing around with file handles but doesn't see the data.

In a shell, there is often a way to transform the output of some command into a single string for the shell, in bash you use the `$(...)` syntax:

```
string_variable=$(command1 arg1 arg2)
```

You will also see backticks but this is deprecated:

```
string_variable=`command1 arg1 arg2`
```

So you can pass the output of a command as an argument to another:

```
string_variable=$(command1 arg1 arg2)
command2 $string_variable
```

But you can also skip the intermediate variable and us the more direct:

```
command2 $(command1 arg1 arg2)
```

Last remark: With `command1|command2` the two commands run in parallel (if there is enough data transferred) and pace each other, while in `command2 $(command1)`, `command1` terminates before `command2` is invoked.